# How to filter django queryset based on the serializer field value?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

serializer:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serailizers.ModelSerializer):
        hrs = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        def get_hrs(self, obj):
           created_at = obj.created_at
           now = datetime.now()
           return (now - datetime).total_seconds() // 3600
         
        class Meta:
           model = MyModel
           fields = "__all__"
```

Now in the api there will be a filter parameter `hr` what it need to do is filter the queryset matching this above calculated hr.

For example:

```
    @api_view(["GET"])
    def get_list(request):
        qs = MyModel.objects.all()
        hr = request.GET.get("hr")
        if hr:
          qs = qs.filter(created_at__hour=hr)
        return MyModelSerializer(qs, many=True).data
```

I want to get matching result if paramter hr=get_hrs() value.

How can I filter like this from serializer fields?

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong placement:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serailizers.ModelSerializer):         
    class Meta:
       model = MyModel
       fields = "__all__"
    hrs = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_hrs(self, obj):
       datetime = SomeModel.objects.filter(id=obj.id).last().datetime
       now = datetime.now()
       return (now - datetime).total_seconds() // 3600
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply but what I want is filter the queryset based on this `hrs` value.

Comment: i dont understand what kind of filter you want, can you clarify more?

Comment: you are looking it from the wrong side, your `serializer` should serialize `already filtered data` from your `views.py`. You cant filter your view according to what your serializer, serialized